# The changes not updating on server

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have build MVC 5 application which works fine when running via VS. When I publish it to the server first time it also works. Now I have made few correction to my css file and publish whole project again but website still see the old css file. I have removed all files from the server and tried few more times but it is still the same. When I check the css file on the server, the changes are inside the file.

I think it is related to MVC bundling as when I check the source it says that is accessing different file which is not even located on the server:

```
 <link href="/Content/cssmain?v=Ikj7NnMg3q9kTHR7ynWOJDQFGMZl3mtVMi_2EkOJxc41" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How can I force VS to minificate my css file again?

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding but no luck

**Edit:**
My bundle set up look like below and all files are located on the server in Content folder.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssmain").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/ilightbox.css",
                  "~/Content/bannerscollection_zoominout.css"));
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried flushing your browser cache? This may have nothing to do with the server.

Comment: Also since you are using a parameter for the css, add an extra one for a timestamp. `cssmain?v=....&ts=@DateTime.Now.ToTicks()`
That way the browser sees a diffrent URL and will load as new rather than cache.

Comment: I have tried different browser, the same thing. I'm not using any parameter for my css, I'm assuming it is done by mvc bundling.

Comment: Thx for showing your bundle. This is my last obvious check question: Have you tried to "Clean" & "Rebuild". The last time one of my CSS failed between that and a new publish, IIS finally took the new CSS.

Comment: As I have few bundles I have swapped them around and it start working, but now some of the jQuery not working. So I think one of the bundle or file in the bundle is causing this. I will go through all of them to find the faulty one. Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried running fiddler to see if the css files are being returned with a 304 or a 200 code?

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is related to MVC bundling as when I check the source it says that is accessing different file which is not even located on the server:

CDN location? External Css lib (yours or 3rd party)? unsure what you meant by "not located on server"?

Yup, it does (look like ASP.net Bundling in action) - check your `Global.asax`, `App_Start/BundleConfig` or `_AppStart` and see if the bundle configuration setup point to/reference the "correct" locations for your css (and or script).

Comment: I have edited question to show my bundling configuration. "not located on server" I mean that file "cssmain?v=Ikj7NnMg3q9kTHR7ynWOJDQFGMZl3mtVMi_2EkOJxc41" doesnt exist on my hosting server, so I don't know from where it is loaded.

Comment: @Whistler if those are the css files that you are referring to, check if you have `@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssmain")` in the page(s) (or _Layout) you expect those styles to be applied. Hth.

Comment: Yes I definitely have this one. As I have few bundles I have swapped them around and it start working, but now some of the jQuery not working. So I think one of the bundle or file in the bundle is causing this. I will go through all of them to find the faulty one. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Is it just you experiencing getting the old css file loaded? Or anyone who views the site?